# How to exclude multiple email addresses from an order query

Tags: php, plugin-craftcommerce2, elementquery

When doing an order query I want to omit results for 2 particular email addresses.

It's easy enough to omit results for one address;

```
$order = Order::find()
    ->isCompleted(true)
    ->email('not email1@somedomain.com')
    ->all();
```

But how do I omit more than one email? If I pass an array using ['not', 'email1@somdomain.com', 'email2@otherdomain.com'] then an error is returned stating that email expects a string.
For example, this doesn't work

```
$order = Order::find()
        ->isCompleted(true)
        ->email(['not', 'email1@somedomain.com', 'email2@otherdomain.com'])
        ->all();
```

Nor does passing in an array of addresses within the array

```
$order = Order::find()
        ->isCompleted(true)
        ->email(['not', ['email1@somedomain.com', 'email2@otherdomain.com']])
        ->all();
```

If I pass in 2 email criteria then only the latter is applied.

There has to be a neat way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree it'd be nice if it worked that way... I'm not sure why it doesn't, but replacing it with a regular `where` clause and `not in` works ok:

```
$order = Order::find()
    ->isCompleted(true)
    ->where(['not in', 'email', ['nobody@example.com','no@example.com']])
    ->all();
```

Comment: Oh gosh that was a bit obvious! I'll give it a whirl, thank you.